# org.postfix.master logs an error every 10 seconds

Tags: macos, osx-elcapitan, launchd, postfix-mta

Every ten seconds, I get errors like these in my OS X El Capitan error logs (with line breaks added here for clarity):

```
3/7/17 09:15:34.104 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]:
   (org.postfix.master[98071]) Service exited with abnormal code: 1
3/7/17 09:15:34.104 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]:
   (org.postfix.master) Service only ran for 1 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 9 seconds.
```

I don’t think I’m using postfix for anything, nor even that I want to.  What’s the best way to handle this?  I’m fine with disabling postfix altogether if there’s no reason to have it running, and also fine with having it running if it’s needed and/or can be made to not spam the console.